# .NET Web API "400 Bad Request" on POST Request When Deploying to IIS local Server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API which has to call another API that also developed in .NET 6. Now I have hosted these 2 APIs on a local IIS server in 2 different websites running on 2 different ports.

I am trying to call API #1 which will call API #2 internally. But I am getting HTTP 400 "Bad Request" error.

In the other way if I run these 2 APIs using Visual Studio 2022, it's working fine and they are able to connect to each other.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you checked your IIS logs?

Comment: What is the response when you make an HTTP call to API #2 directly? Are you getting the correct response?

Comment: Since 400 can be caused by rejection at http.sys level and from your web app, you need to investigate further from Windows HTTP error logs and IIS logs. "working fine" with Visual Studio is usually not helpful at all.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 400 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem

Comment: This error usually occurs for two different reasons 1) The IIS backend is not working.  Possibly failing because it cannot connect to a database 2) IIS you have very limited access to the IIS resources like file system  Most cases the client connects to the IIS as a GUEST and the user does not have access to a needed resource.  IIS are very well protected so hackers cannot attack the machine.  If you are using the file system on IIS move the file(S) to a shared drive where GUEST can read/write.